# how to use textcolor on label of Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

The question is very easy and strange… I'm thinking that it may be a bug... Go it. I have Label where I try to set the background color with key of static resource where it has the Hex value of color. It works good. then, I want to use this color on text instead of background so I have changed it from brackgroundcolor property of Xaml to TextColor property. And it is showed with white color instead the custom color. Should I have to do something in order to set the my custom color instead white?

I have attached sample of resource and the xaml line of Label:

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="Fondo">#38aae1</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    …
    <Label Text="sample" FontSize="15" TextColor="{StaticResource Fondo}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
```

The app is for Android, and version 3.6.0.220655.

Thank you

Comment: Looks a bug. I tried several times make a problem and didn't.

Comment: You may need to post the whole xaml or repro in a simple project you can link to.

Comment: Hey ,did you solve the issue?

Comment: It isn't working yet... I'm updating VS and I will tell you. I have tried to use Uppercase as Guiherme said and nothing. I have tried to delete bin&obj folders and clean&rebuild it but nothing.

Comment: Nothing, I have updated VS and nothing. I have tried
     <Label Text="sample" TextColor="Red" />
and it doesn't work

Comment: Can you share your sample?

Comment: https://github.com/cansado2930/SampleColorLabel I have created a new sample project and I edited the label of sample and it doesn't work me on android. Tell me if you find the problem. thank you

Comment: OK.I will try it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190003/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-cansado2930).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete the folder `bin` and `obj` .Then clean and rebuild your project.I don't think there's anything wrong with your code.Because I use the following code and it works fine both on Android and iOS.

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="Fondo">#38aae1</Color>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </StackLayout.Resources>

    <Label Text="sample" FontSize="15" TextColor="{StaticResource Fondo}" FontAttributes="Bold" />

</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="Fondo">#38AAE1</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    …
    <Label Text="sample" FontSize="15" TextColor="{StaticResource Fondo}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
```

Maybe the Background Color value need to be uppercase or need (")between the text.

Regards