# What is the reason that TextColor of Xamarin Forms doesn't work on android 7.1.1?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

By tests that I and other users have seen that TextColor works correctly on Android 8.0.0 but it doesn't work on a phone with 7.1.1. This question was discovered when the code is correct and Android 8.0 works correctly. This is the before post: [how to use textcolor on label of Xamarin forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55144835/how-to-use-textcolor-on-label-of-xamarin-forms) 
Maybe it a bug, required an upper min-target? 
Thank you

Comment: file a bug report: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: Can you provide more info about the device? It works fine on my android emulator with Android 7.x.

Comment: Very curious... it is a BQ Aquarius X5 Plus

Comment: I  suggest it is because of your device.It is nothing wrong about your code.

Comment: yes... you have reason!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried differents BQ phones and I have found the problem. This model, BQ Aquarius X5 Plus has setted by default the high contrast (experimental) so it delete all colors of text. it is strange that it has configurated by serial...